# When assigning a variable, the encoding fails

Tags: php, encoding

```
$address[$j] = $info['objects'][$j]["ADDRESS"];
```

This is command. Now we look at the result:

```
var_dump($info['objects'][$j]["ADDRESS"]):
```

string(56) "ул Сельскохозяйственная, д. 2, 68"

```
var_dump($address[$j]):
```

string(60) "ќосква, Сельскохозяйственная 2, 68"

Why is this happening?

UPD:

Actual code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($info['objects']); $i++) {

    if ($info['objects'][$i]['AREA'] != '') {

        $clean_info[$j] = $info['objects'][$i];
        $cadastral_number[$j] = $clean_info[$j]['CADNOMER']; // Обновляем кад. номер согласно полученной информации
        $address[$j] = $info['objects'][$j]["ADDRESS"];
        $j++;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($address);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Are those lines following up each other directly? If not, show us the actual code.

Comment: Added actual code.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the dump you've posted earlier, but don't you need the address info of `$info['objects'][$i]['ADDRESS']` instead of `$info['objects'][$j]['ADDRESS']`?

Comment: Yes, it was a mess of variables. Thank!

Comment: You should accept the answer that you received below by clicking the checkmark (not by posting your own answer copying the solution given to you by another user). This is helpful to other users by showing what solution helped you, and it's also a way to thank the user who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't match the dump you've posted earlier, but don't you need the address info of `$info['objects'][$i]['ADDRESS']` instead of `$info['objects'][$j]['ADDRESS']`?